# How to fix PageContext "URLS_SAFE_CHECK__CONTENT_URL_REWRITED" error for sitemap

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

Sitemap XML on bottom have the following error. Currently Using multi language sitemap and this is the urlset used. Due to the script tag at the bottom Sitemap is not being fetched by Google.
How to fix this.

```
<urlset xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="https://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mobile="https://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0" xmlns:image="https://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="https://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
```

> new (class PageContext { constructor(clientKey) { this.client = window[Symbol.for(clientKey)], this.bindEvents(); } bindEvents() { const self = this; var f; history.pushState = (f = history.pushState, function() { const ret = f.apply(this, arguments); return self.onUrlChange(), ret; }); let firstReplaceEvent = !0; history.replaceState = (f => function(params) { var ret = f.apply(this, arguments); return firstReplaceEvent || self.onUrlChange(), firstReplaceEvent = !1, ret; })(history.replaceState), window.addEventListener("hashchange", (function() { self.onUrlChange(); })); } onUrlChange() { this.client.emitToBg("URLS_SAFE_CHECK__CONTENT_URL_REWRITED"); } })('MARIO_POST_CLIENT_almalgbpmcfpdaopimbdchdliminoign')

Comment: It was due to the Urban VPN extension installed in my browser what should those error function. After i disabled the Extension it worked fine